# The Opportunity field isn't getting updated from Flow

Tags: visual-workflow, custom-field, field-update, update

I have created a Record Triggered flow on the Opportunity object which triggers on both creation and update of Opportunity record.

[image]

In my first step I have added a condition to check if a lookup field that exists on Opportunity is Null or not and redirecting the flow based on the outcome of the condition.

**first outcome**

[image]

**Second Outcome**

[image]

In both the cases I am trying to assign some text value to a newly created field on Opportunity called Update flow scratch text to check if the conditions and flow is working as expected.

[image]

But even after I update the Opportunity the Update flow scratch text field in Opportunity is not getting updated with the assigned text. Can someone please let me know if I am doing this right? If not, what needs to be done.

Comment: Can you add screenshot of both outcome in edit decision?

Comment: @snehakem I have edited the question and added the image of both the outcomes now.

Comment: Edit: I missed the second condition screenshot. To me it seems there is no path where you would NOT update the scratch text field. Both paths trigger the update.

Comment: @Christoph Once the Opportunity record is created I create the Record Combination automatically and assign it to the field through the above flow itself. So it won't be empty. Even though if its empty or not, in both cases this flow should populate the value to that custom field on Opportunity right?

Comment: Yes, that is right. From your question I understand that's exactly how it behaves (Quote: "But even after I update the Opportunity the Update flow scratch text field in Opportunity is getting updated with the assigned text"). Am I misunderstanding the problem?

Comment: @Christoph Oh I am sorry, it was supposed to be not getting updated. I have edited the question and corrected it. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: @AkshayVasu Is this a "before" record triggered flow? If not, the you also need to make sure to update your Opportunity record, after adding the text